# Постоянное соединение с сервером SMPP

Tags: php, laravel, daemon, smpp

Есть некий СМС-шлюз требующий постоянного соединения с сайтом. Ну то есть сейчас работает по принципу одна смс одно соединение и проблем не наблюдалось ровно до того момента пока не пришлось отправлять 2 и более смс с сайта за один процес. Для отправки использовался пакет - https://github.com/franzose/laravel-smpp . Но если отправлять более одного смс то отправка не идет вообще и соединение сбрасывается, скрипт вылетает.

Нужно чтобы соединение установилось постоянное с СМС шлюзом, скрипт принимал данные и сразу же отправлял. Сейчас есть идея написать демона на PHP. Но возможно есть какие нибудь другие варианты, подскажите в какую сторону копать.

Язык программирования - PHP 7.3, Фреймворк - Laravel 7, SMPP 3.4

Comment: Демон выглядит самым разумным решением. Вообще, любое потенциально долгое действие стоит выносить в отдельный процесс, чтобы не задерживать отправку ответа пользователю

Comment: Переоткрывайте соединение. Открыли, отправили, закрыли, открыли, отправили, закрыли.

Comment: Либо демон, либо очередь задач типа Gearman. Демон выглядит наиболее подходящим решением и с технической, и с архитектурной точки зрения.